# Sorting arrays by value

Tags: php, sql

I have this post array

```
Array ( 
[imgurl_3] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/05-239x300.jpg
[imgtekst_3] => Write a text for the slide 
[imgurl_4] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/img_2184-300x225.jpg
[imgtekst_4] => Write a text for the slide 
[update_gallery] => Save changes )
```

The numbers in the end of the imgurl and imgtekst are dynamic. So.
I want to pair the imgurl_3 & imgtekst_3, and so on. To update into a database.

Any smart PHP functions for this?

Thanks

Comment: How is that related to _sorting_ ? Can you brief it more ?

Comment: And what do you want to pair? The values, the keys? Only the filenames?

Comment: Sorting was just a term i used i lack of better vocalbury, but the answer below solved my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $array = [
        'imgurl_3' => 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/05-239x300.jpg',
        'imgtekst_3' => 'Write a text for the slide',
        'imgurl_4' => 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/img_2184-300x225.jpg',
        'imgtekst_4' => 'Write a text for the slide',
        'update_gallery' => 'Save changes'
    ];
    $output = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        $intKey = filter_var($key, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if ($intKey) {
            $key = preg_replace('/_\d/', '', $key);
            $output[$intKey][$key] = $item;
        }
    }
    print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for `loop` and select correlated entries:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $whatever; $i++) {

   if(array_key_exists('imgurl_' . $i, $array)) {
      $value = $array['imgurl_' . $i];
      $value2 = $array['imgtekst_' . $i];
   }

   $sqlQuery = '<UPDATE using $value and $value2>';
}
```

Comment: And if `$array['imgurl_0'];` is missing ? And `'<UPDATE using $value and $value2>';` with single quote ?

Comment: @Debflav The UPDATE stuff is obviously just a pseudo-code placeholder.

Comment: @Debflav Updated answer. Due to lacking details in the question I assumed that no values are "missing"

Comment: I read it too fast. Just shocked by the variables between single quote. In any case it seems to be an unreflected response. The owner must give more explanation to give a constructed answer.